# existence and uniqueness of the solution of a PDE

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

There is a standard method to prove the existence and uniqueness in $[0, +\infty)\times (0,1)$ of a PDE as the following:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,r)=\frac{1}{2}r-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u(t,r)$

$u(0,r)=f(r)$,

where $f\in C^\infty(0, 1)$? Thanks for your help

Comment: The existence part is reasonably easy here. Just compute the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Existence - if you set $v = u + r^2/2 - r/2$ then the equation becomes the homogeneous transport equation 
$$ \partial_t v = \frac12\partial_r v$$
thus $v(t, r)$ is given by a function $v(t,r) = V(\frac12 t+r)$ that depends only on $\frac12 t+r$. So since $$v(0,r) = V(r) = f(r) + \frac{r^2}2 - \frac r2 $$

then
$$ u(t, r) = v(t,r) - \frac{r^2}2 + \frac r2  = f\left(\frac12t+r\right) + \frac{(\frac12t+r)^2}2 - \frac{\frac12t+r}2  - \frac{r^2}2 + \frac r2.$$

If $u_1,u_2$ were two solutions then $w = u_1 - u_2$ is a function that solves the homogeneous transport equation
$$ \partial_t w = \frac12 \partial_r w$$
with zero initial condition at $t=0$, so it is $0$ for all time.